# How many non-jews did Nazis kill?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany

It seems to be commonly accepted that the amount of Jewish people killed in the holocaust was about 6 million.

Are there any numbers on how many of the other categories of non-Jewish "non acceptables" that the Nazis killed?

(In this case I am referring to them being killed in concentration camps or in other settings where they were specifically targeted, not in general warfare.)

Are there any numbers for each category (i.e. "political enemies", "disabled", "gypsies", etc) of victim?

Comment: Best estimates range between 10,000,00 and 12,000,000 for total deaths in the holocaust, mostly varying by how one includes victims. For instance how many Russian POWS starved to death should count. Subtracting 5,000,000- to 6,000,000 Jews leaves somewhere between 4,000,000 and 6,000,000 million non-Jews, noting that the estimates are correlated.

Comment: It is hard to categorize "general" civil casualties during the war. E.g. a lot died in famine - should we include them?

Comment: There was a considerable number of Russian civilians not even collected and killed, but just having all their things taken and shoved out into the winter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [Wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holocaust_victims) provides following estimates for the non-Jewish victims:

```
Category        | Amount killed     | Source (in the Wikipedia article)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Disabled        | 270,000           | http://www.holocaust-education.dk/baggrund/eutanasi.asp
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ethnic Poles    | 1.8–2 million     | http://www.projectinposterum.org/docs/poland_WWII_casualties.htm
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Freemasons      | 80,000–200,000    | Freemasons for Dummies, by C. Hodapp p. 85
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Homosexuals     | 5,000–15,000      | The Holocaust Chronicle, Publications International Ltd., p. 108
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Jehovah's       | 2,500–5,000       | Shulman, William L. A State of Terror: Germany 1933–1939
Witnesses       |                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Romani          | 90,000–220,000    | http://www.ushmm.org/wlc/en/article.php?ModuleId=10005219
("gypsies")     |                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Serbs           | 300,000–500,000   | http://www1.yadvashem.org/odot_pdf/Microsoft%20Word%20-%205930.pdf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Slovenes        | 20,000–25,000     | Institute for Contemporary History (Inštitut za novejšo zgodovino),
                |                   | Ljubljana, Slovenia
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Soviet POWs     | 2–3 million       | Berenbaum 2005, p. 125
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Spanish         | 7000              | Pike, David Wingeate. Spaniards in the Holocaust
Republicans     |                   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total (approx.) | 4.5 - 6.2 million |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Some notes about this table:

- The table is here sorted alphabetically according to the victim category.
- The Soviet POWs probably include soldiers captured during war operations. As such they may not all fit the category of those ***not*** killed "in warfare".
- The list does not include Roman Catholics, people of color, various "political" victims (communists, social democrats, socialists, etc) and other smaller groups.
- The categories do not directly map to the categories used on the prisoners clothing (as described e.g. in an answer [to this SE question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23997/what-were-the-52-kinds-of-victims-persecuted-by-the-nazis)).

Comment: This does not include large numbers of "ethnic Belorussians", "ethnic Russians" and "ethnic Ukrainians" (other than POW's) as well as French, Dutch and others killed in mass repressions.

Comment: does this figure include soldiers?

Comment: So, they did not kill Russians?

Comment: @Anixx, sorry but in that table the Russians that were killed I think are only those that were killed in some kind of "camps" (because the information lists them as Soviet POWs), not direct warfare (or related to the warfare). If we would include all the Russians and others that were killed due to their warfare or other cruelty, the numbers would likely be much larger.

Comment: I assume you mean *other* people of color? Many Romani are often considered (or identify as) PoC. (Even some lighter-skinned Jews do, though this is perhaps contentious).

Comment: These figures come from different sources, so there must be some double-counts. For instance, someone can be an ethnic POle, a freemason *and* an homosexual. But the total fork is probably wide enough to remain true in spite of this.